# Eclipse Buildpathchanges wont take effect

Tags: java, eclipse, buildpath

I have got a rather weird eclipse problem. My Software has multiple modules compiled into .jar files. These .jar files are in the Buildpath of the mainContainer project.

When i want to change the code of a module i change the buildpath of the mainContainer porject to use the module project and not its .jar. This way I do not need to reassamble the jar every time i change the module code.

And here is the Problem, the Buildpathchanges wont take effect. When I run or debug the application eclipsesettings say buildpath is refferencing the module project but i know from the behavior of the program that its still using the jar.

Can anybody help me?

PS: Clean or Refresh does not work.

Comment: Can you delete the jar and try restarting eclipse. Also delete bin folder and clean build

Comment: @GodslaveAsad i did but it hasn't done an changes to the problem